# Refresh entire browser or all tabs on click of button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-events

I have to refresh all tabs of a browser in a click of a button that I have made in the HTML page.

Foe axample:- suppose 5 tabs are open in Chrome
     4 tabs are from a different source and 1 tab is of my created Html page.
     I have to refresh all 5 tabs or a particular tab on clicking of a button that I made on my Html page

Comment: You can't control tabs from others sources through your website. What you can do is create a browser plugin that allows refreshing all tabs. Or if all tabs are sources of your page then you could push a websocket message and trigger a refresh through that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`location.reload()` method to refresh or reloads the page

> `boolean(true)` forces it to reload the page from the server.

```
location.reload(true);
```

You can do it in multiple ways as well, you can choose the one you need:

```
location.reload()

location.reload(false)

window.location = window.location

window.location.reload();
```

If you using link then use this :

```
location.href = location.href
```

**UPDATE-1**

I heard you want to refresh all `tabs` in a `Chrome` browser, you can try this.

```
chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(tabs) {
   for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
       chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
   }
  });
```

Source: [Refresh-ChromeTabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

use this for any `event` like `Click`.

Comment: that is refreshing only my current page

Comment: If the tabs are in the same page then I don't think there is an issue, would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: sure, 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="location.reload(true);;">Refresh all Page</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Where are the tabs are? can you share the code as well.

Comment: I have not coded from them. I simply opened them I a browser from google

Comment: You mean refreshing entire browser tabs you mean?

Comment: Yes. Entire browser

Comment: Hmmmm. `location.reload(true)` will refresh entire browser, but I never come across something to refresh all the tabs in the browser. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: I m badly stuck in this problem

Comment: Is there any specific browser you looking into? because not all browsers behave same.

Comment: I am giving more preference to google chrome.

Comment: I just found something for you, updated my code above take a look.

Comment: still giving error on code.error => cannot read property query.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    
 chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(tabs) { 
 for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) { 
 chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url}); 
 } 
 });
 }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id ="btnSubmit">Refresh Pages</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I just searched some more on this, it says that code is meant for extensions. I never come across this requirement before!

Comment: ok, no problem sir..thanks for helping :-)